# Object updated by different thread only partially visible for another thread

Tags: java, string, multithreading, share

I am doing multi-thread programming and encounter a wired issue: object update is only partially visible for another thread. Here is the pseudo code:

Initial state: thread A is running and thread B is blocked

```
Class C {
    public int i;
    public String s;
}
```

Thread A:

```
...
// c is an object of class C and is accessible by both thread A and B
c.i = 10;
c.s = "success";
wakeup thread B:
```

Thread B:

```
// after wakeup
assert(c.i == 10);
assert(c.s.equals("success"));
```

The issue is: in thread B, sometimes the value of string c.s actually is null. But I expect it to have the value "success". On the other hand, if I put Thread.sleep(sometime) before the assert statements, then I can see the expected value for c.s. I do not know why it happens.

I tried to declare filed variable s as volatile but it does not help.

Thanks!

**Update**
Thanks for all the replies/answers. After more experiments and investigations, I believe it is a bug of the framework I am using. The framework manages the suspend/resume of threads and it runs into messy when there are many concurrent requests/connections (like 10k threads).

Comment: Can you show the actual code. Because multithreading doesn't work in the way you are thinking it should. Even before the Thread A has completed the job, Thread B can come into action.

Comment: Volatile should work. Did you mark String s as volatile or whole c object as volatile??

Comment: What mechanism are you using for the `wakeup thread B` part?

Answer (score 3):

When you are working with Multithreading, then all your threads, share your `CPU` amongst them. It is not sure that which thread will complete before and which thread will complete last. It may be possible that the `Thread` that started last might end first. 
It all depends upon the `CPU` scheduling algorithm that is used.

So, if you are running two threads without invoking `sleep` or `wait` on any of them (taht is without `interrupting` any of them), then CPU allocation will switch between both the `Threads`. So, it is certainly possible that `Thread B` gets the CPU even before the `Thread A` has completed.

However, when your `Thread B` is in sleep for the time enough for `A` to complete the job, then the `CPU` is allocated to Thread A till that time. So it has enough time to complete its job (Provided you have only two threads `A` and `B` that are at `runnable` state at that time)

That is why the outcome of your `multithreading` code, is never the same. It keeps on changing on multiple runs. So, when you run your code for some `10 - 15` times. you can see this difference.

To ensure that, your `Thread A` completes before `Thread B`, you can call `wait` in your `Thread B` on a particular instance which `Thread A` is using. Then when `Thread A` completes, it will call `notify` to notify the `Thread B` that it has completed the job, and then `Thread B` can continue,

Comment: I agreed with rohit, Its total depends on thread schedule. there is no certain that which will come first to execute and which will later. every time you will get different result.

Answer (score 3):

You need some synchronization between threads A and B.

Thread A:

```
c.i = 10;
c.s = "success";
c.notify()
```

Thread B:

```
c.wait()
assert(c.i == 10);
assert(c.s.equals("success"));
```

Without this synchronization (or something equivalent, like a `synchronized` block), you are not guaranteed the writes have made it from one thread to another (at all, or in any particular order).

Answer (score 1):

In multithreaded applications, each CPU has a local memory cache and memory operations are heavily reordered for optimization purposes.  You need to make sure that the `C` instance that is shared between the threads is `synchronized`.  This both ensures that one and and only one thread can be making operations do it *and* it makes sure that both threads are using up-to-date memory versions of the object.

If you are using the `synchronized` keyword, it is common to synchronize on a `final` object:

```
  // shared by both threads
  final C c = new C();
  ...
```

Thread A:

```
  ...
  // this allows us to notify on c _and_ synchronizes memory
  synchronized (c) {
     c.i = 10;
     c.s = "success";
     // signal the other thread that is wait-ing
     c.notify();
  }
```

Thread B:

```
  // this allows us to wait for C _and_ synchronizes memory
  synchronized (c) {
     // it's common to test for wait in while loop cause of "spurious interrupts"
     while (c.s == null) {
        // wait for c to be updated
        c.wait();
     }
  }
  assert(c.i == 10);
  assert(c.s.equals("success"));
```

If the `C` object is being constructed by ThreadA then could instead define a final `Object lock = new Object();` for both A and B to synchronize on instead.   You should never synchronize on an object that is being changed because A and B *must* synchronize on the *same* object reference for the wait/notify to work.

> I tried to declare filed variable s as volatile but it does not help.

If both `c.i` *and* `c.s` where volatile then this *should* work but it would depend on how the signaling was done between A and B.  It might have been that `B` woke up too early?  Also, if the `c` object is changing then you'd need to make the definition of `C c` itself also volatile.  The `synchronized` keyword here handles the signaling and the memory synchronization.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using of volatile will solve your question, for example in your case, you can have:

```
class C {
    public int i;
    volatile public String s;
}
```

Declaring a volatile variable means:
The value of this variable will never be cached thread-locally: all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory";
Access to the variable acts as though it is enclosed in a synchronized block, synchronized on itself.

Give it a try!